# Converting unique values in a particular column in excel to new columns and assign values for those columns from another exiting columns using python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert an excel sheet in a particular format to another one.

Current Format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESSd7.png)

Expected Format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBrD1.png)

The Map Criteria list is exhaustive and values may not be present in all cases.

Though I am able to do it in excel itself, need to schedule it to run on a recurring basis. That's why trying to solve it using python.

I tried dataframe aggregate and melt functions which is notgiving the intended result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
df.pivot(index=['Map ID','Map Name'], columns=['Map Criteria'], values='Map Values')
```

Output:

```
                   Brand         Country Department  Gender Product
Map ID Map Name                                                    
1      AAA       Brand A  United KIngdom  Marketing    Male  Laptop
2      BBB       Brand B             NaN    Finance     NaN     NaN
3      CCCC          NaN  United Kindgom        NaN     NaN     NaN
4      DDD           NaN             NaN        NaN     NaN  Mobile
5      DDD           NaN             NaN        NaN  Female     NaN
```

---

Input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Map ID': [1,1,1,1,1, 2,2, 3,4,5],
    'Map Name': [*['AAA']*5,*['BBB']*2,'CCCC',*['DDD']*2],
    'Map Criteria': ['Brand','Department','Country','Product','Gender']*2,
    'Map Values': ['Brand A','Marketing','United KIngdom','Laptop','Male','Brand B','Finance','United Kindgom','Mobile','Female']
})
```